# .NET core 7 windows authentication exception when deployed

Tags: .net-core, openshift, windows-authentication

I have an .NET core application that uses windows authentication. Locally it works fine. However when application is deployed to an openshift platform I get this error after trying to sign in.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AuthenticationException: GenericFailure
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

    AuthenticationException: GenericFailure
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

In my Program.cs I use generic rules for windows auth, nothing fancy:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Looked everywhere for a possible solution but I was unable to find it so I'm now desperate enough to ask here.

Comment: `to an openshift platform` unless the server is joined to the Kerberos domain there's no way your web app (or any other service) can validate the credentials. That's not something you do from inside an application, it's done on the server level